# Invalid identifier in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Im getting an error.
Here's a s/s of the ERD from excel, note mortal_address contains 2 foriegn keys.
Do i need to alter the joins? Title them as a specific type of join?

***List in birth date order, mortal ID, first and last names (may be concatenated), date of birth and social security number for the people who live in Indiana?***

(I tried adding the state_id field, thinking i was using it in a WHERE clause, it should be displayed too-didn't work.)
[image]

The Code:

```
SELECT MORTAL_ID, LAST_NAME|| ‘,’|| FIRST_NAME, DOB, SSN, 
FROM MORTAL
JOIN MORTAL ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE UPPER(ADDRESS.STATE_CODE) = 'IN'
ORDER BY DOB;
```

Comment: You've missed an underscore in the first `mortal_address`. Also, you need to qualify `mortal_id` in the select. E.g. `select mortal.mortal_id`

Comment: @Laurence you should post that as an answer

Comment: Also, make sure that the following part: `||‘,’||` uses single quotes - not a "ticks"!

Comment: Using single quotes, not 'tics', idk wht this site renders it that way.

Comment: Tries your suggestion laurence, now i get 'SELECT MORTAL_ID, LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME, DOB, SSN, 
FROM MORTAL
JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE UPPER(ADDRESS.STATE_CODE) = ‘IN’
ORDER BY DOB;
'  quoted string not properly terminated - removed the concat

Comment: I think what alfasin is saying is that you're using "smart quotes" instead of a regular single quotation mark.  Make sure you're not copying anything from MS Office.

Comment: TY jonearles, thats exactly what i was doing, copying it from word.maybe ill use notepad instead.